# Ruby | Loop to show variables basted on number

Tags: ruby, loops

For 20 minutes, i'm figuring out how to show variables based on the loop his current number, but i can't manage to figure it out.

I got it to work with a string, but not with a variable.

```
foo1 = 'one'

foo2 = 'two'

foo3 = 'three'

foo4 = 'four'

foo5 = 'five'

foo6 = 'six'

foo7 = 'seven'

foo8 = 'eight'

foo9 = 'nine'

foo10 = 'ten'

10.times do |n|
  n+=1
  puts foo{n}
end
```

The code needs to do this:

```
puts foo1 + "\n" + foo2 + "\n" + foo3 + "\n" + foo4 + "\n" + foo5 + "\n" + foo6 + "\n" + foo7 + "\n" + foo8 + "\n" + foo9 + "\n" + foo10 + "\n"
```

Comment: It's not clear. Post pls what you expect to get

Comment: How to use .times to show multiple variables that are in a count, example: Puts foo + N so it will show foo1 on loop1, foo2 on loop2 etc,..

Comment: When you find yourself in need to do this, it's a 99% sure sign that you need to use an array or hash instead of individual variables. See @drenmi's answer, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
NUMBERS = %w[one two three four five six seven eight nine ten].freeze

# Not so good if the number of items changes
10.times do |n|
  puts NUMBERS[n]
end

# Better, but might not fit the homework requirements ;-)
NUMBERS.each do |number|
  puts number
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**This answers your exact question, but JFYI, it's a terrible idea and for what it should have been please see the answer by @Drenmi** (credits to @SergioTulentsev)

```
foo1 = 'one'
foo2 = 'two'
foo3 = 'three'
foo4 = 'four'
foo5 = 'five'
foo6 = 'six'
foo7 = 'seven'
foo8 = 'eight'
foo9 = 'nine'
foo10 = 'ten'

1.upto(10) { |n| puts binding.local_variable_get "foo#{n}" }
```

Comment: You realize you're enabling terrible practices? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I do. I am answering the questions as they were stated, though.

Comment: But maybe add a "This answers your exact question, but JFYI, it's a terrible idea and here's what it should have been..."?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you are free to add an answer with a better practice

Comment: @SergioTulentsev added.